# datastax hive select count(*) on table which only 3 records,but need 1hour to count() ,why?

Tags: hadoop, hive, datastax-enterprise

hive> select * from  example;
OK
1       hello yang
2       hello bear
3       aaa
Time taken: 51.273 seconds   **-> that's ok !**
hive> select count(key) from  example;
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Starting Job = job_201309170341_0001, Tracking URL = ... 
Kill Command = /usr/bin/dse hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=10.10.5.153:8012 -kill job_201309170341_0001
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of **mappers: 1537**; number of reducers: 1

Then wait for 1 hour ,I get the count : 3    !

why need so many time ? and why mappers so big: 1537 ?

Comment: this test cluster have 6 nodes:  2 cassandra node,2 hadoop node,2 solr node; token_numbers for cassandra node is 256, for others is 1;

Comment: the table example is created in cassandra by cqlsh; schema is :CREATE TABLE test.example (
  key int PRIMARY KEY,
  data text
) WITH
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
  compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'SnappyCompressor'};

Answer (score 2):

Do you enable the vnodes? It looks like you enable vnode. We are working on support hadoop on vnodes, but before it's done, it's recommended to disable it for a hadoop data center/cluster

Comment: yes,I had  enabled the vnodes. thank you very much. I will disable it  .